# Where did the Add New Custom Field go?

Tags: custom-field, metabox

In the latest version of WP it's gone. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it still exists, you just have to enable showing it, with screen options http://theandystratton.com/2011/wordpress-3-1-admin-bar-and-i-cant-see-custom-fields